# Microsoft Graph API rate limit for retriving Onenote content

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am using MSGraph endpoints to access Onenote notebooks. Just wanted to understand what is rate limit per user . Secondly does this rate limit depends upon how you register your application with Microsoft application registration  portal.

Comment: Is it a coding problem. I think no.

Comment: I haven't faces throttling as of now. Just wanted to confirm before I start working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the blog post below:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/01/12/onenote-api-throttling-and-how-to-avoid-it/

> ...if you're running into throttling (429's) during development, you
>   can simply change your user or your app (this does require giving
>   permissions again) and keep coding/testing against the API.

As for the public limits of the OneNote API, they aren't public unfortunately. If you're running into them in a valid scenario, do contact us.

Comment: This link - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/ states the rate limits to be 10k per user for 10 mins. @Jorge Aguirre - I don't quite follow why you say the the rate limits are not published. Thanks.

Comment: @Jorge Aguirre, is there any more detail about user-level or app-level rate limits for the OneNote API that you can share these days?